# Joining multiple times on the same table for different criteria vs. once on aggregated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have a view that joins a table multiple times on the same criteria, something like:

```
Select
m.ID,
a.value as value1,
b.value as value2,
c.value as value3,
d.value as value4

from
main_table m
left join other_table a on m.ID = a.ID and a.X = 'this'
left join other_table b on m.ID = b.ID and b.X = 'that'
left join other table c on m.ID = c.ID and c.X = 'third'
left join other table d on m.ID = d.ID and d.X = 'other'
```

I am wondering if it would be more or less efficient to instead combine the four tables and aggregate them, so that I could do it all in one join:

```
Select
m.ID,
value1,
value2,
value3,
value4

from
main_table m
left join (select ID,
           MAX(case X when 'this' then value end) value1,
           MAX(case X when 'that' then value end) value2,
           MAX(case X when 'third' then value end) value3,
           MAX(case X when 'other' then value end) value4
           from ( 
           select ID,X,value from other_table
           where X = 'this'
           union all
           select ID,X,value from other_table
           where X = 'that'
           union all
           select ID,X,value from other_table
           where X = 'third'
           union all
           select ID,X,value from other_table
           where X = 'other')
           GROUP BY ID) AS A
on A.ID = m.ID
```

I am asking before experimenting because in reality, the view is much more complicated than that and would take a long time to rewrite, so I want to be sure I am not wasting my time.

Basically, my question is whether the cost of performing aggregates and a `group by` would outweigh the cost of performing those multiple joins. Also, I think it is relevant to include the fact that this view contains *many* other joins (15-20) so I am trying to optimize by reducing that number in any way.

**EDIT** Also I feel it is relevant to add that there are linked servers involved and these two tables are on different databases; another reason why I am trying to reduce the number of joins.

Any insight or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The queries are different unless you can guarantee no more than one match in the other tables.  Also, is "other table" always the same table?

Comment: I'd probably stick with the first option. If you're worried about performance though, make sure you have an index on `X`. You could even add a few filtered indexes for each value of `X`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How so? Wouldn't I get `NULL` for `value` either way if the ID does not exist in the other table?

Comment: @Samcd . . . I phrased that incorrectly.  I meant no more than one, not at least one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes other_table is always the same table

Comment: Thanks @DavidG I don't have experience with filtered indexes but I will look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most performance questions, you need to test the different versions on your data on your system.  But, I think the aggregation query you want is:

```
Select m.ID, value1, value2, value3, value4
from main_table m left join
     (select ID,
             MAX(case X when 'this' then value end) value1,
             MAX(case X when 'that' then value end) value2,
             MAX(case X when 'third' then value end) value3,
             MAX(case X when 'other' then value end) value4
      from other_table
      group by ID
     ) A
     on A.ID = m.ID;
```

The advantage of aggregation is that adding more values does not much change the performance.  Adding new joins can affect performance, so at some point, the aggregation will probably outperform the joins.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience I had faced the similar problem in a particular schema design where we were storing custom properties and their values in a separate table for an entity and when we had to query back all custom property data for an instance of the entity we had to join back to same table multiple times.

We had effectively used `PIVOT` syntax to circumvent multiple joins. In your case this would be like.

```
Select
m.ID,
[this],[that],[third],[other]
from
main_table m
left join
    (
        select id,[this],[that],[third],[other]
            (select id, X from other_table )s
                PIVOT
            ( 
                max(value) 
                    for X in ([this],[that],[third],[other])
            )p 
    )t
on t.id=m.id
```

**N.B:** Please note that this resulted a massive performance gain in our case by avoiding all those `JOINS`

Comment: +1 because it does work, and also because this was the first time I have been able to work the PIVOT function after reading your answer. But I accepted the other answer because it is closer to what I had been using, and because it accepts multiple criteria (`MAX(case when X = 'this' AND ...`) which I need in other parts of this view